# Calculating the radius of a black hole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, estimation

Does the Schwarzschild equation give you the radius of any black hole? When I use it and plug in a black hole mass of a million solar masses, I get a radius of 8 km, that's seems way too small, but is it correct? If that's not correct, then is there a way to estimate the black hole's radius if the only piece of information you have is the mass?

Comment: A static black hole's radius depends only on the mass and is proportional to it. Since the Sun's Schwarzschild radius is a couple of kilometers, you must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In Schwarzschild coordinates,  the line element for the Schwarzschild metric is:

Source: [Schwarzchild Radius Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric)

$${\displaystyle c^{2}\,{d\tau }^{2}=\left(1-{\frac {r_{\mathrm {s} }}{r}}\right)c^{2}\,dt^{2}-\left(1-{\frac {r_{\mathrm {s} }}{r}}\right)^{-1}\,dr^{2}-r^{2}\left(d\theta ^{2}+\sin ^{2}\theta \,d\varphi ^{2}\right),}$$

> where:
>
> when ${\displaystyle {d\tau }^{2}}$ is positive, $τ$ is the proper time (time measured by a clock moving along the same world line with the test particle)
>
> $c$ is the speed of light,
>
> $t$ is the time coordinate (measured by a stationary clock located infinitely far from the massive body),
>
> $r$ is the radial coordinate (measured as the circumference, divided by 2π, of a sphere centered around the massive body),
>
> $θ$ is the colatitude (angle from north, in units of radians),
>
> $φ$ is the longitude (also in radians),
>
> $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius of the massive body, a scale factor which is related to its mass $M$ by $r_s =2GM/c^2$, where $G$ is the gravitational constant.
>
> The analogue of this solution in classical Newtonian theory of gravity corresponds to the gravitational field around a point particle.

When we apply the GR equations to this problem, we can suppress $θ$ and $φ$ and. as we are assuming a static, stationary source, which produces a time independent metric, so that implies $dt \to -dt$, and removes cross-terms  such as $dtdr$, $dtd\phi$, $dtd\theta $ and spherical symmetry elimates the  other mixed terms, leaving us with a diagonal matrix.

As Javier  states above,

> A static black hole's radius depends only on the mass and is proportional to it.

$$R_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$
$$R_s = \frac{2(10^{6})(2\times 10^{30}\,{\rm kg})(6.67\times10^{-11}\,{\rm m}^3\,{\rm s}^{-2}\,{\rm kg}^{-1})}{(3\times 10^8\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-1})^2} $$
$$R_s = 3 \times 10^6\,{\rm km}$$

Compared to 3km for the Schwarzchild radius of the sun.

You must have done something wrong...

My thanks to Kyle Oman for his help.